# Angular 5 - How to getElementById from element inside *ngIf div?

Tags: html, angular

I want to add an overlay that slides into view on my page. To do it, I am setting the style.width of the div during overlay open and close. The problem is the div is controlled by a *ngIf, and is undefined when my .ts code sets the *ngIf true and tries to set the div's width.

How can I get this working?

**Component HTML:**

```
    <div  *ngIf="showOverlay === true">
       <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay" style="margin-top: 25px;">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeOverlay()">&times;</a>
         <div class="overlay-content">
           <a href="#">Overlay is working!</a>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="showOverlay === false" id="content" style="padding: 30px;">
    ...
    </div>
```

**Component TS:**

```
    public showOverlayFcn() {
      this.showOverlay = true;
      this.openOverlay();
    }  

    public openOverlay() {
      document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.width = "100%";
    }

    public closeOverlay() {
      document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.width = "0%";
    }
```

Thanks! Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a conditional ngStyle attribute on the div with ID of myOverlay:

```
[ngStyle]="{'width': showOverlay ? '100%' : '0%'}"
```

Comment: That sure is an elegant solution. Thanks Richard, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not following the angular way. To get any element angular recommends to use `@ViewChild`. SO the proper way would be something like below:

```
<div *ngIf="showOverlay === true">
   <div #myOverlay class="overlay" style="margin-top: 25px;">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeOverlay()">&times;</a>
     <div class="overlay-content">
       <a href="#">Overlay is working!</a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showOverlay === false" id="content" style="padding: 30px;">
...
</div>
```

And on your class file access it like this:

```
@ViewChild('myOverlay', { static: false }) myOverlay: ElementRef;
```

Even after this if you're not able to get the element then trigger a change detection like: `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`. Please remember to inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that {static:  false} construct, so I can't solve the error: Argument of type '{ static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'static' does not exist in type '{ read?: any; }'. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Then have you tried by providing the read property like this way: `@ViewChild('myOverlay', { read: ElementRef, static: false })`?

Comment: Yes, same error. That's OK, Richard gave me the solution that works. Thanks Khairul.

Comment: You're welcome. Give a last try put the element ref in the `div` where the `*ngIf` exists `<div #myOverlay *ngIf="showOverlay === true">`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use setTimeout function as there maybe delay to enable element by ngIf.

```
public openOverlay() {
  setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.width = "100%";
  }, 100);
}
```